# How to execute a function that passes the row that is double clicked as a parameter, but creating this row through code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an empty table, and I add rows to it using a button. And to each row I add a dblclick event listener, so far so good. The problem is that in the event, I need to execute a function that receives the row I'm double clicking on. In other tables that are already full, I just pass 'this' to the function that is executed when I double click on the row. [In this image you can see how I am trying to do it, it is inside a loop because I want to add this to all the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd63Q.png)

Comment: In the event listener. `event.currentTarget` will be the row that was clicked.

Comment: Hello @Barmar, I have tried it and it worked, I thank you very much for commenting so quickly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as Barmar commented, I just had to add `event.currentTarget` and it worked. [you can see it in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FYpr.png)